# Mapping an Array of Strings and Assigning Them to an Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my code, I'm trying to map through an array of strings using observables and I want to see that value inside of an input. I printed my code on the console and I can see the array but I could not assign this to an input field. I also get the error `Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[]>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.` I want to see the array element inside it but what I see is `{{ slider$ | async }}`. What should I do to fix my code?

HTML:

```
<input type="input" value="{{ slider$ | async }}" />
```

TS:

```
const slides = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4'];
let slider$: Observable<any[]>;
slider$ = of(slides).pipe(map((response) => {return response;})).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Can you be more clear what you’re looking for. The source of slider$ is an array. Do you want to see four inputs, or the first of the array etc.

Comment: I want to see the first element of the array @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74280648-obs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="input" value="{{ slider$ | async }}" />
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  slides: string[] = ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4'];

  slider$: Observable<string> = of(this.slides).pipe(
    tap(console.log), // ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3', 'Slide 4']
    map((arr: string[]) => {
      return arr[0]; // map to 1st element of the array
    }),
    tap(console.log) // 'Slide 1'
  );
}
```

When you do this `{{ slider$ | async }}` the async pipe is subscribing (and cleaning up subscription on component destroy) to the observable `slider$`. In your code you are subscribing directly so that `slider$` becomes a Subscription rather than the expected Observable, hence the error. If you wish to debug part way through the stream you can use the `tap` pipeable operator. This is also used for side effects.